# Problem 1 Conway singularities. Page 132.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|<1$ and $f$ is analytic. By considering the function $g:D\to D$ defined by $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-a}{1-\overline{a}f(z)}$
where $f(0)=0$, prove that
$\frac{|f(0)|-|z|}{1+|f(0)||z|}\leq |f(z)|\leq \frac{|f(0)|+|z|}{1-|f(0)||z|}$ for $|z|<1$.

$g(0)=0$ obvius but I can't prove that $|g(z)|\leq 1$ to be able to use  Lemma's Schwartz and conclude. Why is it fulfilled? I can't prove this part.

Comment: Note that $g = T \circ f$ where $T$ is an automorphism of the unit disk.